# no module found by python (selenium) mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip

so i have been trying to download selenium to python on a macbook pro 2015 using pip3 in terminal(it says here i downloaded):

```
Arons-mbp:~ Aron$ pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)
```

however when i want to run a program on python i wrote on another computer (windows: but i changed the code for it to work on a mac) (its just a basic test program to automatically click on a web game):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin')
driver.get('http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/')
time.sleep(5)
cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bigCookie"]')
while 1 != 0:
cookie.click()
```

i get back this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Aron/Documents/cookieclicker.py", line 1, in <module>
        from selenium import webdriver
    File "/Users/Aron/Documents/selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
        from selenium.webdriver import chromedriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver'; 'selenium' is not a package
```

I have searched all over the internet and i can't seem to find a solution 
thank you :)

edit: using sudo pip3 install selenium i get:

```
Arons-mbp:~ Aron$ sudo pip3 install selenium
Password:
The directory '/Users/Aron/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Aron/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)
```

using sudo -H pip3 install selenium i get:

```
Arons-mbp:~ Aron$ sudo -H pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from selenium) (1.24.1)
```

And i sill get the same error after running my program.

when i run:

```
192:~ Aron$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        18.1   
selenium   3.141.0
```

so i do have it installed

edit: so i got a bit further i looked up where the selenium package was and copied it next to my file but then it couldn't find urllib3 so i did the same and now when i run it i get two different errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/bleieraron/Documents/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
        stdin=PIPE)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1516, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/bleieraron/Documents/cookieclicker.py", line 7, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin')
    File "/Users/bleieraron/Documents/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
        self.service.start()
    File "/Users/bleieraron/Documents/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
        os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'bin' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Is it possibly a permission issue? Did you try sudo pip3 install selenium?

Comment: Do you have multiple Python binaries on your system -- python2, python3, python3.6 python3.7 etc? Have you tried opening the version of python that you are running your script with and typing `import selenium` in the interactive python interpreter to see if it loads?

Comment: starting your code with python3 ? some times i have a brain lagg and name my test .py like the name i like to test `selenium.py` - note this will destroy your import

Comment: @Mark i just tried it and i get the same result. i am not sure what you mean with your first question. doesn't python 3 use python 2?

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 are two separate installations. How are you running the script? Do you run `/usr/bin/python3 <script name>` or have you a shebang at the top of the script e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @Mark neither i didn't know what that was until you mentioned it(i am quite new to python). I read up on it however, it still doesn't work, still gives the same error

Comment: @aronbleier are you evoking your script with `python3`?

Comment: @duhaime yes i am